# sails won't populate user (undefined)

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I try to associate a chat message with an user. But the populate function gives me an user `undefined`

```
//message.js
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    user:{
      model: 'User'
    },
    message:{
      type:'string',
      required:true
    }
  }
```

};

I save an entry of a message and try to populate the messages with the user afterward

```
module.exports = {

  test: function(req, res){

    var data = {
      user : "5533b9f00fe12ff020c67225",
      message : 'auto generated'
    };

    Message.create(data, function messageCreated(err, message){

      if(err) return res.negotiate(err);

          Message.find().populate('user').exec(function(err, messages){
            if(err) return res.negotiate(err);

            res.json(messages);

          });

      });

  }

};
```

But it always gives me user `undefined` back, when I try to populate.

What I have tried so far:

- get one user and populate all his messages: works!
- find one user according the found Message's associated userId the step before, to ensure the user exists: works!
- change the Assosiation so another Message instead of an User and than populate the Messages with the one "master message" : works!

I don't understand why it works with other models but not the User model

Comment: your user id is correct ? User exist in DB ?

Comment: yes I also tried to get the user after the message from the message's user id and it worked

Comment: Show us your User model maybe there is a problem with it (your association with Message model)

Comment: with other models as association It worked without the other association side, but here is my message assosiation from my user anyway:     messages: {
    collection: 'Message',
      via: 'user'
  },

Comment: You can try to add dominant: true

Comment: what is your PK in your message model? And you might want to show the relevant parts of your user model as well.

Comment: My Pk is the Mongodb Id. I have read that it would make some problems in similar cases. But I cannot simply change my Pk, the app is too big

Comment: Could I iterate trough each retrieved message model and find() the according user model? Or are there too many database operations then. Doesn't populate use the same amount of operations? Thank you

Comment: Does `Message.find()` return values (IDs) for `user` key without using `populate('user')`?

Comment: yes without populate('user') , i get the user's ID stored in user

Comment: Can you please include your users model so that we can take a look at it.